# What does "Get on to somewhere" mean?

Tags: meaning

I was watching a movie (Fences) when I noticed that the actors kept using this phrasal verb "get on to/get on down to" when I searched up the meaning online I couldn't find anything besides what I already knew.

"Get on down to the basement!"

"Why do you wanna get on talking about death?"

"Get on to the kitchen!"

Comment: I think it just means "to go (down) to" - if you look up "get on" you will see the meaning "get along": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20along - the first definition, "to progress", basically means "to go towards", so I am guessing that's where this comes from. Someone who's more familiar with 50's Pittsburgh Black English Vernacular might have a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

In English, prepositions are often little more than ["noise words"](https://care.icims.com/s/article/Understanding-Search-Noise-Words) that convey little or no information. *Sometimes* they're required or encouraged for syntactic reasons, but there are many contexts where native speakers disagree over which, if any, preposition(**s**) should be used in any given context.

I specifically highlighted that optional pluralising '**s**' above because it might not be obvious to all learners that native speakers often chain together *multiple* optional prepositions - and this doesn't always have much (or *any*) effect on the meaning of the containing utterance. Consider, for example,...

> 1: *Get **on down to** the basement!*
>    2: *Get **down to** the basement!*
>    3: *Get **on to** the basement!*
>    4: *Get **to** the basement!*

...where all four versions effectively mean the same thing. Some people might not like *all* of them, but they all occur in natural speech. In these examples, the only preposition that's actually *required* is the final ***to*** (*Get the basement!* with *no* preposition is never acceptable).

Doubtless there are even more extreme examples of such "cascading optional prepositions", but one that comes to mind is...

> 5: *I'm going **off out down to** the pub*

...where again, only ***to*** is actually required. But most permutations (using any number of the other three prepositions, in various different sequences) could in fact occur, from at least *some* native speakers.

---

Regarding OP's second example, I must say that I personally feel the (*totally* unnecessary) use of prepositions there looks a bit ignorant / "affected". It's much simpler to use none at all (except the syntactically required ***about***)...

> *Why do you wanna **talk** about death?*

---

I don't want to overstate my initial point that these words *convey little or no information*. In any given context, they may at least impart a slight "nuance". Thus with my first three examples, ***on*** has overtones of ***get along*** (get **moving, shift yourself!**), and ***down*** has direct semantic relevance (the basement is ***lower*** than speaker's current location). But any such nuances are often vague and/or unimportant.

Comment: I agree with your analysis here, and wanted to add to my above comment, since you bring up a good point regarding sentence 2. “To get on talking” does not mean “to go to talking,” as I may have implied with my comment- that would make no sense. I would say maybe it means “to start talking” if anything besides simply “to talk.”

Comment: There's a limit to how deeply I'd want to analyse OP's example #2 (as pointed out, it strikes me as rather "ignorant / sloppy" phrasing anyway). But I personally don't think it's valid to assert that the specific usage there unambiguously carries implications of either ***continue*** OR ***start** talking about death*.  To me, it could be either or neither.

Comment: ...come to that, it could even be clumsy misspeaking where the intended sense is *get **off** on talking about death* (with the implication that the addressee derives some kind of perverted pleasure from discussing the topic).